Blazor web app using MudBlazor: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' random issue hosted on IIS
I'm working on a .NET 8 Blazor app using MudBlazor deployed on IIS. It works fine on the local and dev servers but throws the following error on only on prod server:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at MudBlazor.AbstractLocalizationInterceptor.DefaultLanguageResourceReader(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   at MudBlazor.AbstractLocalizationInterceptor..ctor(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, MudLocalizer mudLocalizer)
   at MudBlazor.DefaultLocalizationInterceptor..ctor(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, MudLocalizer mudLocalizer)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithFewArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreatePropertyInjector>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType, IComponentRenderMode callerSpecifiedRenderMode, Nullable`1 parentComponentId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame[] frames, Int32 frameIndex, Int32 parentComponentId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessPendingRender()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(Int32 componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderHandle.Render(RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.HandleExceptionViaErrorBoundary(Exception error, ComponentState errorSourceOrNull)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasksWithErrorHandling(Task task, ComponentState owningComponentState)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(Int32 componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.BeginRenderingComponent(IComponent component, ParameterView initialParameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.BeginRenderingComponent(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.EndpointHtmlRenderer.RenderEndpointComponent(HttpContext httpContext, Type rootComponentType, ParameterView parameters, Boolean waitForQuiescence)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<<InvokeAsync>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<<<Main>$>b__5>d.MoveNext() in E:\agent-cs\_work\153\s\*****\Program.cs:line 107
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Program.<>c.<<<Main>$>b__0_3>d.MoveNext() in E:\agent-cs\_work\153\s\*****\Program.cs:line 105
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

The missing dll is already there and work fine but this error appears randomly.
I can't reproduce this error locally, and after redeploying the same code base on IIS, it worked fine. The IIS site configuration is the same in all environments. And the application is using windows authentication.
Below are the package references:-
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ClosedXML" Version="0.104.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="7.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" Version="8.0.1" />


Your issue is not related to Blazor or MudBlazor. How do you deploy your code to the production environment? I guess the troublemaker is there.

@FarzadM., We are using the Azure DevOps pipeline, and the same artifact is deployed on each environment. And, yes It doesn't look like a Blazor or MudBlazor issue. It has happened a few times randomly when the application starts, and later it resolves automatically. We redeployed the same code, but that doesn't always help. We are waiting for more logs from the prod server.

My suggestion is to use something like dotnet publish --configuration Release --output ...  --runtime win-x64 as your pipeline script. I've had similar issues, and I always solve them with this runtime switch.

Sure, I will try that and update here on how it goes.

Try adding the Microsoft.Extensions.Localization extension by nuget in your project

Yes, we tried that, and it was throwing the same error for another DLL, which is also present in the bin folder.     'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60''
